# Adjoint natural transformations

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

> Is there a name for antiparallel natural transformations between ${\bf Cat}$-valued functors such that the components at each object form an adjunction?

That is, suppose we have functors $F,G:\mathcal{C}\rightrightarrows{\bf Cat}$ and natural transformations $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$, $\beta:G\Rightarrow F$ such that $\alpha_C\dashv\beta_C$ for all $C\in{\bf Ob}_\mathcal{C}$. Is there an established name for pairs of natural transformations related in this manner?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the notion of adjunction in the 2-category $[\mathcal{C}, \textbf{Cat}]$. I forget if the coherence condition is automatically satisfied (satisfiable) in this case.

Comment: @ZhenLin That sounds about right, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: The pointwise property is not enough to guarantee $\alpha \dahsv \beta$ in $Fun(C, Cat)$. Take $C= \Delta^1$, then a natural transformation from $C_0 \to C_1$ to $D_0\to D_1$ admits a right adjoint if and only if both $C_i\to D_i$ do, and the canonical mate square commutes. In this case, the right adjoint is the canonical mate square, so if there is some other isomorphism making this square with the right adjoints commute, this would give a $\beta$ which is not right adjoint to $\alpha$ as a transformation. Although I guess here I am really working in the $2$-category of $(2,1)$-functors

Comment: So maybe it is different in the $2$-category of strict, i.e. $1$-functors (I guess what I called $(2,1)$-functors above is also called pseudofunctors)

Comment: If you have a natural transformation $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$ (or even a pseudo natural one) such that each component $\alpha_C$ has a right adjoint, then these right adjoints automatically assemble into a *lax* natural transformation $\beta : G\Rightarrow F$ such that $\alpha \dashv \beta$ in the 2-category of lax natural transformations.  The same is true if $\alpha$ is only colax natural, although in that case the coherence conditions are fancier.  And dually if a lax natural $\beta$ is given with pointwise left adjoints.  See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/doctrinal+adjunction.

Comment: @MikeShulman That is interesting, thank you --  when you say the $2$-category of lax natural transformations, do you mean the $2$-category that has lax natural transformations as its $1$-cells or some construction where lax natural transformations form the objects of a $2$-category?

Comment: Sorry, the former.